# How to create costum listview control in a UserControl?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

What i want to do is when i drag the UserControl in form1 designer from the toolbox i will be able to use/control the ListView control.

This is the UserControl code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{
    public partial class lvnf : UserControl
    {
        ListViewNF lvnfs;

        public lvnf()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            lvnfs = new ListViewNF();
            lvnfs.Location = new Point(50, 50);
            lvnfs.Size = new Size(50, 50);
            lvnfs.View = View.Details;
            lvnfs.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            lvnfs.SuspendLayout();
            lvnfs.LabelEdit = true;
            lvnfs.Columns.Add("From", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            lvnfs.Columns.Add("Subject", 200);
            lvnfs.Columns.Add("Date", 300);
            lvnfs.Sorting = SortOrder.None;
            //lvnf.ColumnClick += lvnf_ColumnClick;
            //lvnf.Click += lvnf_Click;
            //lvnf.SelectedIndexChanged += lvnf_SelectedIndexChanged;
            this.Controls.Add(lvnfs);
            lvnfs.ResumeLayout(false);
        }

        class ListViewNF : System.Windows.Forms.ListView
        {
            public ListViewNF()
            {
                //Activate double buffering
                this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);

                //Enable the OnNotifyMessage event so we get a chance to filter out 
                // Windows messages before they get to the form's WndProc
                this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.EnableNotifyMessage, true);
            }

            protected override void OnNotifyMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
            {
                //Filter out the WM_ERASEBKGND message
                if (m.Msg != 0x14)
                {
                    base.OnNotifyMessage(m);
                }
            }
        }

        private void ListViewNFTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when i drag the UserControl into form1 desginer i can use lvnf but it's the UserControl not the ListViewNF control. I want to to be able to use the ListViewNF control from inside the UserControl.

And i want that the ListViewNF will be named as lvnf so when i will drag the UserContro to form1 designer i will be able to use th lvnf(ListView Control) and not the UserControl.

Comment: expose a reference to the Listview inside the usercontrol as a property

Comment: Great working. Thanks.